# Use lxml in Maya 2013?

Tags: python, lxml, maya

Recently I found a lxml library to parse XML documents. It shows an improvement of efficiency comparing to default python xml library. So, I copy lxml directory to (MAYA Path)\Python\Lib\site-packages, but it comes out an error.

**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found**

Simple copy is not a way to use lxml in Maya 2013. How can I use it?

Comment: Provide the link to the package repo you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using a dll that does not match with Python version used.

If you're using Windows, follow [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml), download / install lxml that matches your python version and architecture.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the dependency on version specific binaries use the built in [ElementTree module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead of LXML. The APIs are more or less identical, but ElementTree imposes no additional dependencies -- this makes it a lot easier to distribute to users.

There's also [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which is pure python (no binaries needed) and is great if you want to scrape HTML as well as or in addition to XML

LXML is faster than ElementTree but I've never found an application where the speed boost paid for the hassles of distribution.

Pretty much anything beats going through the python DOM though :)

Answer (score 0):

> The lxml XML toolkit is a Pythonic binding for the C libraries **libxml2** and **libxslt**.

So you have to install the corresponding C libraries before using lxml.

The simple way to install lxml is using **pip**:

```
$ sudo pip install lxml
```

There're other ways to install lxml. Here's the [installatioin doc](http://lxml.de/installation.html) and [Static linking on Windows](http://lxml.de/build.html#static-linking-on-windows)